# Is there any stotra for worship of Nagaraja (Adishesha or Vasuki)?

Tags: stotra, naga

I know the Navanaga sloka, but I could not find any stotra for Nagaraja.

Comment: There is: https://www.dhevee.org/nagaraja-gayatri-mantra/

Comment: You want a Vasuki Stotra or a Sloka will do?

Comment: A Stotra for Vasuki would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sarpa suktam which is usually chanted in South Indian temples and during special occasions like naga panchami. Below is the stotra. It is also available in English transliteration on internet.

> ब्रह्मलोकेषु ये सर्पा शेषनाग परोगमा:।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।1।।
>
> इन्द्रलोकेषु ये सर्पा: वासु‍कि प्रमुखाद्य:।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।2।।
>
> कद्रवेयश्च ये सर्पा: मातृभक्ति परायणा।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।3।।
>
> इन्द्रलोकेषु ये सर्पा: तक्षका प्रमुखाद्य।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।4।।
>
> सत्यलोकेषु ये सर्पा: वासुकिना च रक्षिता।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।5।।
>
> मलये चैव ये सर्पा: कर्कोटक प्रमुखाद्य।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।6।।
>
> पृथिव्यां चैव ये सर्पा: ये साकेत वासिता।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।7।।
>
> सर्वग्रामेषु ये सर्पा: वसंतिषु संच्छिता।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।8।।
>
> ग्रामे वा यदि वारण्ये ये सर्पप्रचरन्ति।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।9।।
>
> समुद्रतीरे ये सर्पाये सर्पा जंलवासिन:।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।10।।
>
> रसातलेषु ये सर्पा: अनन्तादि महाबला:।
>
> नमोस्तुतेभ्य: सर्पेभ्य: सुप्रीतो मम सर्वदा।।11।।

[Source](https://m-hindi.webdunia.com/article/astrology-tantra-mantra-yantra/%E0%A5%A4%E0%A5%A4%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AA-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%A4%E0%A5%A4-113040600023_1.htm), [English Source](http://www.bharatiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/Sarpa-Stotram-Eng-v1.pdf)

You can also find vedic suktam for sarpa in [this](https://animeshnagarblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/paippaladiya-sarpa-suktam/) website. And also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171013063034/http://www.bharatiweb.com:80/wp-content/uploads/Sarpa-Sooktam-2-Eng-v1.pdf).

Comment: You source 3 link seems to be broken...i tried to edit but it seems the link itself is incomplete...

Comment: @YDS i dont know maybe someone help to incorporate that link

Comment: i tried to fix it..pls verify...

Comment: You added Devanagari in answer and given link in English. It should be vice versa.